# CComboBox - How to change the color of the static with Drop List Style

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, mfc, gdi

I want to know if it's possible to change the color of the text (and of the small arrow) and the background of the static in a `CCombobox` with the `Drop List` style.

My class is derived from `CComboBox` and I've tried with the function `CtlColor` and `OnCtlColor`, but nothing seems to change the color of the ComboBox.

Here's a picture of the control with the Drop List style :

[image: ComboBoxDropList]

I would like the text and the arrow to change to `RGB(0, 255, 255)` and the background to `RGB(255,255,0)`.

Here's my function `CtlColor()` :

```
HBRUSH CColoredComboBox::CtlColor(CDC *pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC || nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT) 
    {
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255,255,0));
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 255, 255));
    }
    return m_brBkgnd;
}
```

It works for the style Dropdown, but not for the Drop List.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CBS\_DROPDOWNLIST combo fails to respond to WM\_CTLCOLOR... under Windows UX theming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031621/cbs-dropdownlist-combo-fails-to-respond-to-wm-ctlcolor-under-windows-ux-themi)

Comment: You can change the colour of the text and background by making the combobox owner draw.  I know no way to change the colour of the arrow.

Comment: I think you have the names mixed up. Dropdown is the one with edit box, it won't work this method. Droplist has no edit box and it should work, provided you have the old 3-D look. The attached image shows modern UI look, so in that case neither listbox will show any change unless they are ownerdraw.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know arrow color can be changed or not but, color of combobox can be changed. With help of `OnChildNotify()` function, you can retrieve child `HDC` and then particular child `HDC` can be changed.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMyComboBox message handlers

BOOL CMyComboBox::OnChildNotify(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pLResult) 
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    if(WM_CTLCOLOREDIT != message)
        return CComboBox::OnChildNotify(message, wParam, lParam, pLResult);

    HDC hdcChild = (HDC)wParam;
    if(NULL != hdcChild)
    {
        SetBkMode(hdcChild, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdcChild, RGB(255, 255, 0));
        SetBkColor(hdcChild, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        *pLResult = (LRESULT)(m_Brush.GetSafeHandle());
    }

    return TRUE;
//  return CComboBox::OnChildNotify(message, wParam, lParam, pLResult);
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: But this ComboBox is the DropDown Style ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways - easy and hard. The hard way is to complete DrawItem with ownerdraw to handle all the cases. The easy way is to put two combos on top of each other in your dialog resource and hide the one you're not going to use.
Maybe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05339d2a-982c-4324-953a-38b3f54754f2/owner-draw-comboxbox-with-cbsdropdownlist-style-does-not-retain-aero-style?forum=vcgeneral) can give you some ideas.